# NGINX nested locations configuration

Tags: html, nginx, static

I am trying to configure nginx for a small static "webhosting" for a few products. I am trying to configure nested locations in nginx, but still getting errors.

My location configuration is

```
location /pets {
  index index.html;

  location  ~ /pets/rabbits {
    index rabbits.html;
  }
```

I am trying to serve `index.html` when you go to `myserver.org/pets` and `rabbits.html` when `myserver.org/pets/rabbits` is visited.

Pets are working but rabbits not. I am getting error 301 when I go without trailing slash, and 404 with trailing slash.

What I am doing wrong, please?

Thanks

EDIT: And also I am trying to match location `/pets` and `/pets/` with no success (to be matched both). Using regexes like `/pets(?:/(.*))?$` etc. Is there a simple way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Is `rabbits.html` located at `/path/to/root/pets/rabbits/rabbits.html`? Because the `index` directive only works with URIs that end with a `/` and resolve to a directory.

Comment: No it is located in pets/rabbits.html only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `rewrite` as it's more appropriate for your case, e.g.:

```
rewrite ^/pets/rabbits/?$ /pets/rabbits.html last;
location /pets/ {
  index index.html
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it.